# Azure AKS stuck in a bad state with error VM scale set and load balancer must belong to same virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-aks

While migrating a cluster we moved the vnet used by the AKS from one resource group (the one with the nodepool created by the AKS) to a different RG where we created the AKS cluster. This however, resulted in an unexpected state. The original vnet in the nodepool resource group stayed as is while it copied the vnet in to the AKS RG with the same ID. So now we have to vnet with the same name but in two different resource groups. Afterwards when we tried to create a new nodepool we received the following error:

> Code="VMScaleSetMustBelongToSameVnetAsLB" Message="VM scale set
> references virtual network
> /subscriptions/12345/resourceGroups/project-test-k8s-mc-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/AKS-VNET-931
> which is different than load balancer virtual network
> /subscriptions/12345/resourceGroups/project-test-k8s-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/AKS-VNET-931. VM scale set and load balancer  must belong to same virtual network."

The cluster was created with a managed vnet.

We tried searching for ways to change the load balancer created by AKS to use a different vnet, we do not see any options. We cannot afford to recreate the cluster at this stage. So do we have any other options to fix this issue?

Comment: You should open a support ticket

Comment: Do you mean on the Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, with Azure support

Answer (score 0):

**There was no direct option to change the load balancer created by AKS to use a different VNet**. If the load balancer uses an IP address in a different subnet, ensure the AKS cluster identity also has read access to that subnet. The VM scale set and load balancer must always belong to the same virtual network.

We can modify only address space and subnet only. Found one blog by "Ajay Kumar" refer [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ajayz.kumarz/modify-the-address-space-and-subnet-of-an-aks-cluster-with-kubenet-plugin-and-azure-managed-vnet-c5a3be52b40d) for [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard) information.